# Bash save/redirect stdout and stderr when program is killed

Tags: bash, redirect, stdout

When ProgramA is killed by an external process (killed: 9), I cannot redirect its output (std/stderr) or save it to a variable.

ProgramA:

```
$ ./ProgramA arg1
  This is on stderr
  This is on stdout
  Killed: 9
```

Failing to save to a variable:

```
$ ProgramA_Output=`ProgramA arg1`
$ echo "$ProgramA_Output"

$
```

Redirection to a file also does not work:

```
$ ProgramA arg1 > output.txt
$ cat ./output.txt
$
```

Any clues to save / redirect the output?

Comment: If it's the shell itself that's killed, you can't do **anything** on a SIGKILL. That's the whole point of using it instead of a SIGTERM (and, conversely, the point of using SIGTERM instead whenever possible): It can't be trapped/handled, and so is guaranteed to complete immediately [barring blocking syscalls or the like], but *also* guaranteed not to let the program being killed clean itself up, flush its output buffers, etc.

Comment: That said, did you write `ProgramA`? If so, you can force it to flush its buffers earlier.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not write `ProgramA` and I'm not sure what's even causing it to be killed.

Comment: well, figuring that out is a good place to start. If you're on Linux, I'd suggest checking `dmesg` to see if it's the OOM killer; if it's not, `sysdig` is a tool that can trivially tell you which process on your OS is sending the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely immediate cause here is that your program is only flushing its buffers on a line-by-line basis when output is to a TTY; hence, when redirected to a file or a FIFO, it hasn't flushed yet when the SIGKILL is delivered -- and since a SIGKILL can't be trapped or delayed, it has no opportunity to perform a flush at that time.

If you're on a GNU platform, you can use `stdbuf` to modify this behavior by default:

```
stdbuf -o0 ./ProgramA arg1 >output.txt
```

...or...

```
output=$(stdbuf -o0 ./ProgramA arg1)
```

Since you know that it flushes when output is to a tty (since output shows up immediately when run without redirection), you can also use `unbuffer` (a tool which ships with `expect`) to simulate that effect:

```
output=$(unbuffer ./ProgramA arg1)
```

---

However, the surest thing to do is to modify the source of `ProgramA` to explicitly perform a flush operation after every write you want to ensure is complete -- and to only use SIGKILL *when absolutely required*. (A common practice is to use a SIGTERM, wait for a substantial time period, and only then resort to a SIGKILL).